# How to show response from database to codeigniter view in row format

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I am showing data from database to codeigniter view in row format but right now the problem is If I showing two different id's data than it will combine and make confusion to recognize each id data.

This is how it's shown currently:

[image]

But I want to show like this:

```
id:
1

job title
Business Analyst

Experience Required
3 years 

id:
2 

job title
Business Analyst

Experience Required
3 years
```

Here is the codeigniter view table code:

```
<table class="table table-bordered" style="margin-top:20px;" id="dataTable">
                    <thead>
                      <tr>
                        <th>
                        id
                        </th>
                      </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <?php
                    $ids = array();
                      foreach($resultadmin as $r){
                      $ids[] = $r['id'];
                    ?>
                      <tr id="banner_<?php echo $r['id'];?>">
                        <td>
                            <?php echo $r['id']; ?>
                        </td>   
                      </tr>
                    <?php
                      }
                    ?>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <table class="table table-bordered" style="margin-top:20px;" id="dataTable">
                    <thead>
                      <tr>
                        <th>
                        Job Title
                        </th>
                      </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <?php
                    $ids = array();
                      foreach($resultadmin as $r){
                      $ids[] = $r['id'];
                    ?>
                      <tr id="banner_<?php echo $r['id'];?>">
                        <td>
                            <?php echo $r['title']; ?>
                            <form method="" action="<?php  echo site_url(); ?>/Upload_Controller/" target="_blank"> 
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Apply Job</button>
                            </form>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                     <?php
                      }
                    ?>
                    </tbody>
                </table>

                <table class="table table-bordered" style="margin-top:20px;" id="dataTable">
                    <thead>
                      <tr>
                        <th>
                        Description
                        </th>
                      </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <?php
                    $ids = array();
                      foreach($resultadmin as $r){
                      $ids[] = $r['id'];
                    ?>
                      <tr id="banner_<?php echo $r['id'];?>">
                        <td>
                            <?php echo $r['description']; ?>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    <?php
                      }
                    ?> 
                    </tbody>
                </table>

                <table class="table table-bordered" style="margin-top:20px;" id="dataTable">
                    <thead>
                      <tr>
                        <th>
                        Summary
                        </th>
                      </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <?php
                    $ids = array();
                      foreach($resultadmin as $r){
                      $ids[] = $r['id'];
                    ?>
                      <tr id="banner_<?php echo $r['id'];?>">
                        <td>
                            <?php echo $r['summary']; ?>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    <?php
                      }
                    ?> 
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <table class="table table-bordered" style="margin-top:20px;" id="dataTable">
                    <thead>
                      <tr>
                        <th>
                        Duties And Responsibilities
                        </th>
                      </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <?php
                    $ids = array();
                      foreach($resultadmin as $r){
                      $ids[] = $r['id'];
                    ?>
                      <tr id="banner_<?php echo $r['id'];?>">
                        <td>
                            <?php echo $r['responsibilities']; ?>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                     <?php
                      }
                    ?>
                    </tbody>
                </table>

                <table class="table table-bordered" style="margin-top:20px;" id="dataTable">
                    <thead>
                      <tr>
                        <th>
                        Qualification
                        </th>
                      </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <?php
                    $ids = array();
                      foreach($resultadmin as $r){
                      $ids[] = $r['id'];
                    ?>
                      <tr id="banner_<?php echo $r['id'];?>">
                        <td>
                            <?php echo $r['qualification']; ?>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                     <?php
                      }
                    ?>
                    </tbody>
                </table>

                <table class="table table-bordered" style="margin-top:20px;" id="dataTable">
                    <thead>
                      <tr>
                        <th>
                        Experience Required
                        </th>
                      </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <?php
                    $ids = array();
                      foreach($resultadmin as $r){
                      $ids[] = $r['id'];
                    ?>
                      <tr id="banner_<?php echo $r['id'];?>">
                        <td>
                            <?php echo $r['experience']; ?>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    <?php
                      }
                    ?> 
                    </tbody>
                </table>

                <table class="table table-bordered" style="margin-top:20px;" id="dataTable">
                    <thead>
                      <tr>
                        <th>
                        Details
                        </th>
                      </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <?php
                    $ids = array();
                      foreach($resultadmin as $r){
                      $ids[] = $r['id'];
                    ?>
                      <tr id="banner_<?php echo $r['id'];?>">
                        <td>
                            <?php echo $r['details']; ?>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    <?php
                      }
                    ?> 
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

Comment: can you provide a `print_r($resultadmin);` so its locally testable for us? the issue is you are using multiple loops for each section instead of one. its also weird your doing this with tables and not divs, its more difficult to manage this way (atleast in the format you want)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you could do it. You basically need one main loop, if it were just a normal table or a bunch of divs it would be easier.

If you want to exclude a field by name just add it to the `array('id', 'title')`.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
        foreach ($resultadmin as $jobs) {
            $id = $jobs['id'];
            foreach ($jobs as $k => $v) {
                if (in_array($k, array('id', 'title'))) {
                    continue;
                }
                ?>
                <table class="table table-bordered" style="margin-top:20px;" id="dataTable">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>
                                <?php
                                if ($k == 'title') {
                                    echo 'Job Title';
                                } else {
                                    echo ucfirst($k);
                                }
                                ?>
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr id="banner_<?php echo $id; ?>">
                            <?php if ($k == 'title') { ?>
                                <td>
                                    <?php echo $v; ?>
                                    <form method="" action="<?php //echo site_url();   ?>/Upload_Controller/" target="_blank"> 
                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Apply Job</button>
                                    </form>
                                </td>
                            <?php } else { ?>
                                <td><?php echo $v; ?></td>   
                            <?php } ?>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <?php
            }
            echo '<hr>'; // might make things more clear...
        }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Where `$resultadmin` looks like this:

```
$resultadmin = array(
    0 => array(
        'id'               => 1,
        'title'            => '1Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.',
        'description'      => '1Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.',
        'summary'          => '1Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.',
        'responsibilities' => '1Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.',
        'qualification'    => '1Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.',
        'experience'       => '1Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.',
        'details'          => '1Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.',
    ),
    1 => array(
        'id'               => 2,
        'title'            => '2Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.',
        'description'      => '2Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.',
        'summary'          => '2Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.',
        'responsibilities' => '2Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.',
        'qualification'    => '2Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.',
        'experience'       => '2Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.',
        'details'          => '2Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.',
    ),
);
```

Comment: Hi, If i don't want to show id here than where i have to change the code. I am having difficulties while understanding your code.

Comment: Basically when you are presenting data from a database which is stored in rows and columns as just rows with a single column you are making your life difficult even though I understand why you might want to do it! So we have to do this nested foreach, if you want to exclude a column I will update my answer.

Comment: I will be very thankful to you if you will exclude showing id.

Comment: I made few changes which results excluding showing "id". First i prevent getting id in select statement like " $this->db->select('title,description,summary,responsibilities,qualification,experience,details'); ". than I replace title with id such as " <?php
        foreach ($resultadmin as $jobs) {
            $title = $jobs['title'];" .By these changes i managed to get desired output but don't know what is now doing in this statement " $title = $jobs['title'];"

Comment: Well previously it was applying the id too all the tr ids as you had in your original post. See the part where `banner_<?php echo $id; ?>` in your new thing youd change it to `$title` - although im not sure it is even necessary if youre not using it for some js function or whatever

Comment: Yes its unnecessary to have ids in tr tags.  So i removed ids in tr tags and replace title.  But now i have used your updated code with id and job title removed. I don't know why job title is removed too?

Comment: Just as an example if you wanted to exclude more fields. Just remove title from the array. You also don't have to do the select statement thing

Comment: I am using your updating code. But in your code you have added this if condition " if (in_array($k, array('id', 'title'))) {
                    continue;
                }" due to which job title field disappeared which i don't want.

Comment: Thanks for your help, i just changed your if condition and replace title with id, and it working. "if (in_array($k, array('id', 'id'))) { continue; } "

Comment: If you only want to exclude one you can just replace in array with `if($k=='id') `